# How can I count the total number of times a specific string was found in a text file, and store it in a variable?

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ with KiXtart script to automate automate a process.

I would like know how I can count the total number of times a specific string was found in a text file and store it in a variable that will be used in KiXtart.

Comment: In Find Result Window (F7), we can see the total number of results, but how can i store it in a variable ?

Comment: If you want to do the count in kixtart there's some example code here which should do the trick:http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=66303